# Link em tabela de computadores que submeta um campo para uma ficha

Tags: php, query, select

Bom dia pessoal,
Possuo uma tabela, que é um `query select` dos dados dos dispositivos que eu controlo. Nele tenho vários elementos, como Nome, MacAddress e IP, por exemplo.
Na coluna IP, eu desejo por um `link` e a partir dele (o IP do meu dispositivo) eu fazer uma outra *query* filtrando os dados somente daquele dispositivo.

Segue meu código:

```
echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="270"><center><b>NOME DO DISPOSITIVO</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>IP</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center><b>MAC ADDRESS</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>GATEWAY</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>REDE</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center><b>MÁSCARA DA REDE</b></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {  
    echo '<table id="tborpo"><tbody><tr id="tbcorpo">';
    echo '<td id="nome" width="270">'.$aux["NAME"].'</td>';
    **echo '<td width="130"><a href="fichas/ficha.php">'.$aux["IPADDR"].'</a></td>';**
    echo '<td width="230"><center>'.$aux["MACADDR"].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="130">'.$aux["IPGATEWAY"].'</td>';
    echo '<td width="130"><center>'.$aux["IPSUBNET"].'</center></td>';
    echo '<td width="230"><center>'.$aux["IPMASK"].'</center></td>';
    echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
}
```

`

Comment: Não entendi uma coisa. Você quer que esse campo IP seja um link pra você clicar e ser redirecionado para uma página com os dados desse link?

Comment: Perfeitamente. Não sei como fazer esse link "submeter" (não sei se _submit_ é o melhor método) para uma função php que filtre os campos.

Comment: Você quer fazer isso de forma dinâmina na mesma página onde se encontra ou quer ser redirecionado mesmo pra outra, como um href?

Comment: Queria como um href mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Para criar um link em uma estrutura como esta, basta colocar a tag `<a>` e inserir um href dinâmico, cujo valor reflita o registro que você está exibindo:

```
echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="270"><center><b>NOME DO DISPOSITIVO</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>IP</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center><b>MAC ADDRESS</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>GATEWAY</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center><b>REDE</b></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center><b>MÁSCARA DA REDE</b></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    echo '<table id="tborpo"><tbody><tr id="tbcorpo">';
        echo '<td id="nome" width="270">'.$aux["NAME"].'</td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><a href="fichas/ficha.php"><a href="/URL/DA/PÁGINA/DE/INFORMAÇÕES/DO/COMPUTADOR/?ipAddr='.$aux["IPADDR"].'">'.$aux["IPADDR"].'</a></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center>'.$aux["MACADDR"].'</td>';
        echo '<td width="130">'.$aux["IPGATEWAY"].'</td>';
        echo '<td width="130"><center>'.$aux["IPSUBNET"].'</center></td>';
        echo '<td width="230"><center>'.$aux["IPMASK"].'</center></td>';
    echo '</tr></tbody></table>';

}
```

Comment: Filipizaum, eu tenho mais ou menos, 1000 dispositivos. Não tenho como criar 1000 páginas. Por isso eu pensei em uma _query_

Comment: Faz uma única página para exibir as informações de um computador qualquer.

Nesta página você faz a consulta do computador baseada em um campo unique.

Comment: CONSEGUI! Utilizei o método "GET" e apliquei uma _query_ em cima da variável _ipAddr_ ! Obrigado a todos que contribuíram!